# How to use vectors as features in scikit learn

Tags: python, vector, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to use vector representations of words as feature for a scikit learn classifier. I have tried SVC. Here is the code

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import csv
import numpy as np
from gensim.models import word2vec
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('text.model.bin', binary=True)

with open('1000.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    listwords = csv.reader(csvfile)
    features = []
    labels = []
    n = 0
    for row in listwords:
            if n>=199:
                break
            try:
                line = [int(row[2]),np.array(model[row[0]])]
                features.append([line])
                labels.append([row[1]])
                n+=1
            except KeyError:
                pass
                features.append([])
                n+=1
clf = SVC()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
vocab_obj = model.vocab['anne']
print (clf.predict([vocab_obj.count,model['anne']]))
```

The function model[X] returns a vector.

I get the error : ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be several issues w.r.t. the representation of your labels and features.

As far as I can see from your code, `labels` appears to be a list of lists (possibly) containing strings (probably looking like `[['0'], ['1'], ...]`), however the `fit()` function expects a numpy array of integers. When building your labels list, try using `labels.append(int(row[1]))` (ignore the cast to `int` if `row[1]` is already an integer). If your labels are category names (e.g. `sports`, `politics`, or whatever), the you'd need to use a [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) first. Before calling `fit()` you might also want to convert your labels list to a numpy array: `y = np.array(labels)`.

Your `features` list appears to have a similar problem, but looks as if it might be a triple nested list. The `fit()` function expects the data matrix to be a `n_samples x n_features` matrix. If you are working with word vectors, then `n_features` is the dimensionality of your word vectors and `n_samples` the number of documents in your csv file.

For getting a document representation from the word vectors you'd need to compose them in some way. Commonly, simply adding or averaging all vectors in a document has been found to be a strong baseline. Note that its hard to tell from your example what the meaning of `int(row[2])` in `line = [int(row[2]),np.array(model[row[0]])]` is.

I'd encourage you to post some more information of how a single line in your csv file looks like if you're still struggling to get this to work.